# Is there a way to add columns that share another column in common?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to add the column 'calorie' when the 'start_date' and 'meal_type' are the same to produce a matplotlib plot. I am able to plot the 'calorie' and 'start_date' but i can't figure out how to add the columns and be able to plot them. Here is a sample of my data sorted on the 'start_date':
using ; (semi-colon) as delimiter

```
amount;meal_type;start_time;name;calorie  
2;100001;2/19/19 10:11;Black Label Bacon Original(Hormel);180  
1;100001;2/19/19 10:11;Medium Cheddar Cheese(Kraft);120  
2;100001;2/19/19 10:11;Egg;148  
1;100004;2/19/19 13:37;NUT-rition Heart Healthy Mix(Planters);190  
1;100002;2/19/19 16:35;Mayo Real Mayonnaise(Kraft);90  
0.5;100002;2/19/19 16:35;Celery;3  
1;100002;2/19/19 16:35;Classic Cole Slaw Mix(Dole);20  
1;100002;2/19/19 16:35;Chunk Light Tuna in Water (Pouch)(StarKist Foods);70  
0.5;100002;2/19/19 16:35;Baby Spinach;3.5  
1;100005;2/19/19 20:13;String Cheese(Polly-O);80  
0.5;100005;2/19/19 20:13;2% Mexican Cheddar Jack(Kraft);40  
1;100005;2/19/19 20:13;Magic Pop(Kim's);15  
1;100005;2/19/19 20:13;Pepperoni Stix(Hormel);110  
1;100003;2/19/19 20:24;Parmesan Cheese (Grated);22  
1;100003;2/19/19 20:24;Skinless Chicken Breast;130  
1;100003;2/19/19 20:24;Pork Cracklins(Original Mac's);80  
0.4;100003;2/19/19 20:24;Whole Milk Mozzarella Cheese(Polly-O);32  
0.5;100003;2/19/19 20:24;100% Natural Tomato Sauce(Hunt's);10  
2;100001;2/20/19 9:15;Egg;148  
2;100001;2/20/19 9:15;Black Label Bacon Original(Hormel);180  
1;100001;2/20/19 9:15;Medium Cheddar Cheese(Kraft);120  
1;100004;2/20/19 15:00;NUT-rition Heart Healthy Mix(Planters);190  
1;100002;2/20/19 16:22;100% Natural Tomato Sauce(Hunt's);20  
1;100002;2/20/19 16:22;Pork Cracklins(Original Mac's);80  
1;100002;2/20/19 16:22;Skinless Chicken Breast;130  
1;100002;2/20/19 16:22;Parmesan Cheese (Grated);22  
1;100002;2/20/19 16:22;Whole Milk Mozzarella Cheese(Polly-O);80  
1;100005;2/20/19 19:36;String Cheese(Polly-O);80  
1;100005;2/20/19 19:36;Pepperoni Stix(Hormel);110  
0.5;100003;2/20/19 23:30;Almond Meal Flour(Bob's Red Mill);80  
1;100003;2/20/19 23:30;Zucchini Summer Squash (Without Salt, Drained, Cooked, Boiled);29  
3.6;100003;2/20/19 23:30;Baked or Broiled Cod;126  
0.5;100003;2/20/19 23:30;Basil Pesto(Barilla);110
```

My intentions are to ensure 'start_time' and 'meal_type' are same and add calories as new column as 'total_calories' for day with the following results:

```
amount;meal_type;start_time;name;calorie;comment;total_calories  
2;100001;2/19/19 10:11;Black Label Bacon Original(Hormel);180;;  
1;100001;2/19/19 10:11;Medium Cheddar Cheese(Kraft);120;;  
2;100001;2/19/19 10:11;Egg;148;;776  
1;100004;2/19/19 13:37;NUT-rition Heart Healthy Mix(Planters);190;;190  
1;100002;2/19/19 16:35;Mayo Real Mayonnaise(Kraft);90;;  
0.5;100002;2/19/19 16:35;Celery;3;;  
1;100002;2/19/19 16:35;Classic Cole Slaw Mix(Dole);20;;  
1;100002;2/19/19 16:35;Chunk Light Tuna in Water (Pouch)(StarKist Foods);70;;  
0.5;100002;2/19/19 16:35;Baby Spinach;3.5;183.25;  
1;100005;2/19/19 20:13;String Cheese(Polly-O);80;;  
0.5;100005;2/19/19 20:13;2% Mexican Cheddar Jack(Kraft);40;;  
1;100005;2/19/19 20:13;Magic Pop(Kim's);15;;  
1;100005;2/19/19 20:13;Pepperoni Stix(Hormel);110;;225  
1;100003;2/19/19 20:24;Parmesan Cheese (Grated);22;;  
1;100003;2/19/19 20:24;Skinless Chicken Breast;130;;  
1;100003;2/19/19 20:24;Pork Cracklins(Original Mac's);80;;  
0.4;100003;2/19/19 20:24;Whole Milk Mozzarella Cheese(Polly-O);32;;  
0.5;100003;2/19/19 20:24;100% Natural Tomato Sauce(Hunt's);10;;249.8  
2;100001;2/20/19 9:15;Egg;148;;  
2;100001;2/20/19 9:15;Black Label Bacon Original(Hormel);180;;  
1;100001;2/20/19 9:15;Medium Cheddar Cheese(Kraft);120;;776  
1;100004;2/20/19 15:00;NUT-rition Heart Healthy Mix(Planters);190;;190  
1;100002;2/20/19 16:22;100% Natural Tomato Sauce(Hunt's);20;;  
1;100002;2/20/19 16:22;Pork Cracklins(Original Mac's);80;;  
1;100002;2/20/19 16:22;Skinless Chicken Breast;130;;  
1;100002;2/20/19 16:22;Parmesan Cheese (Grated);22;;  
1;100002;2/20/19 16:22;Whole Milk Mozzarella Cheese(Polly-O);80;332;  
1;100005;2/20/19 19:36;String Cheese(Polly-O);80;;  
1;100005;2/20/19 19:36;Pepperoni Stix(Hormel);110;;190  
0.5;100003;2/20/19 23:30;Almond Meal Flour(Bob's Red Mill);80;;  
1;100003;2/20/19 23:30;Zucchini Summer Squash (Without Salt, Drained, Cooked, Boiled);29;;  
3.6;100003;2/20/19 23:30;Baked or Broiled Cod;126;;  
0.5;100003;2/20/19 23:30;Basil Pesto(Barilla);110;;577.6
```

Comment: for some reason my post didn't come out the way I intended. I used * as a delimiter not knowing that it is als used for text formatting. I will try to resubmit in a better format if needed.

Comment: Could you explain how the number `776` was calculated for `start_time 2/19/19 10:11`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want do the sum of each `meal_type` on the same `date`.

We can do the following:

```
# If needed convert the start_time column to type datetime
df['start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_time'])

# Calculate the correct calories
df['calorie_recalc'] = df['amount'] * df['calorie']

# Calculate the sum of each meal per datetime (start_time)
m = df.groupby(['meal_type', 'start_time'])['calorie_recalc'].transform('sum')
df['total_calories'] = np.where(df['meal_type'] == df['meal_type'].shift(-1), np.NaN, m)

# Print 3 columns to show output
print(df[['meal_type', 'start_time', 'total_calories']])
    meal_type          start_time  total_calories
0      100001 2019-02-19 10:11:00             NaN
1      100001 2019-02-19 10:11:00             NaN
2      100001 2019-02-19 10:11:00          776.00
3      100004 2019-02-19 13:37:00          190.00
4      100002 2019-02-19 16:35:00             NaN
5      100002 2019-02-19 16:35:00             NaN
6      100002 2019-02-19 16:35:00             NaN
7      100002 2019-02-19 16:35:00             NaN
8      100002 2019-02-19 16:35:00          183.25
9      100005 2019-02-19 20:13:00             NaN
10     100005 2019-02-19 20:13:00             NaN
11     100005 2019-02-19 20:13:00             NaN
12     100005 2019-02-19 20:13:00          225.00
13     100003 2019-02-19 20:24:00             NaN
14     100003 2019-02-19 20:24:00             NaN
15     100003 2019-02-19 20:24:00             NaN
16     100003 2019-02-19 20:24:00             NaN
17     100003 2019-02-19 20:24:00          249.80
18     100001 2019-02-20 09:15:00             NaN
19     100001 2019-02-20 09:15:00             NaN
20     100001 2019-02-20 09:15:00          776.00
21     100004 2019-02-20 15:00:00          190.00
22     100002 2019-02-20 16:22:00             NaN
23     100002 2019-02-20 16:22:00             NaN
24     100002 2019-02-20 16:22:00             NaN
25     100002 2019-02-20 16:22:00             NaN
26     100002 2019-02-20 16:22:00          332.00
27     100005 2019-02-20 19:36:00             NaN
28     100005 2019-02-20 19:36:00          190.00
29     100003 2019-02-20 23:30:00             NaN
30     100003 2019-02-20 23:30:00             NaN
31     100003 2019-02-20 23:30:00             NaN
32     100003 2019-02-20 23:30:00          577.60
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, with the data here now I should be able to graph the results. Thanks a lot for your help.